# Constructing sentences

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm wondering if there are other native ways to say:

> I got us that room at the Woodford in this weekend.

No special context, assume that the husband told the sentence to his wife.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With US English, I would use "for" rather than "in" - "I got us that room at the Woodford for this weekend." The sentence construction is fine. Variants:

- I reserved a room for next weekend - at the Woodford.
- I reserved that room at the Woodford for this weekend.
- I got us a room, at the Woodford, for this upcoming weekend.